# Flask: How can I send a text from python to a HTML textArea

Tags: python, html, flask, frontend

I just started learning how to use flask in python and I'm doing a little practice to get information from my frontend , analyze it and then send the result back to the frontend in a TxtArea. I'm able to get the information from the first txtArea and analyze it, but I'm not sure of how to send the analysis output back to the frontend.

[image]

Basically I should be showing 'Hello world' in the right txtArea as a result of the input of the left txtArea.

Here is my code.

````
@app.route('/analisis',methods=["POST","GET"])

def analisis():
    if request.method=="POST":
        content=request.form["text1"]
        result=analysis(content)
        return redirect(url_for("analisis"))
    else:
        return render_template('analisis.html')```
````

And this is what I got for the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#"  method="post">
  <h1>Input</h1>

<p><input type="submit" value="Analizar"/></p>

<textarea id="txt1" name="text1" rows="4" cols="50">

  </textarea>

  <textarea id="txt2" name="text2" rows="4" cols="50">

  </textarea>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure this line is correct? `result=analysis(content)` ?

Comment: also what do you get when hit Analizar?

Comment: What you are asking for is more complex than just printing "Hello World". Here you are passing a string in the left window for which there is not way to interpret if print is a function. In short if you are posting data and you want to get that data on right do this:
`return render_template("hello.html", content=content)`
and this in html:
`<textarea id="txt2" name="text2" rows="4" cols="50">
{{ content }}
</textarea>`

Comment: @RajVerma, What I'm doing is an interpreter so the output of 'Analizar' should be 'Hello world'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your data from the `textarea`, process it and return both values to the html

below is a sample route

```py
@app.route('/sample', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def sample():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sample_input = request.form.get('text1')
        sample_output = sample_input + ' -> Processed'
        return render_template('index.html', sample_input=sample_input, sample_output=sample_output)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
```

sample html template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/sample" method="post">
    <h1>Input</h1>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Analizar"/></p>

    <textarea id="txt1" name="text1" rows="4" cols="50">
        {{ sample_input }}
  </textarea>
    <textarea id="txt2" name="text2" rows="4" cols="50">
        {{ sample_output }}
  </textarea>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

When there is a `POST` requst, it will update the `textarea` with the appropriate values, when it is a `GET` request, it will give a blank `textarea`

Comment: could you please help me understand how this is giving you just the "Hello World" when I tested it, it still gives me `print("helloworld")  -> Processed` for the input `print("helloworld") `. Thanks in advance. @DanielLópez

Comment: @RajVerma Sure! I adapted your solution to my code, as you can see above  I have this `result=analysis(content)` in my code, I built a compiler, so whatever the input is, it will return an output since I've created programming language. Then `result` will display what the output should be in my programming language. You can try it out here: https://danielle500.herokuapp.com/ on the `Analisis` tab.

Comment: @DanielLópez ah i see, you already have the compiler coding done in the “analysis” function.

Comment: @RajVerma from my understanding of the question, it is not about parsing `print('helloworl')` but about sending data to the template. I assume `analysis(content)` will take care of the parsing, my sample code only set the input and output text. replacing `sample_output` with the value of `analysis` will display it in the appropriate textarea

Answer (score 1):

```
content=request.form["text1"]
result=analysis(content) #I assume you have a function that analyzes this parameter
url_for('remove', variable=result)
```

and then in HTML

```
{{ variable }}
```